# Prove that there are infinitely many numbers n for which $\tau(n)^{\tau(n)-1} = n$

Tags: number-theory

Looking to prove that there are infinitely many numbers $n$ for which $\tau (n)^{\tau (n)-1} = n$.  Can this proof be done by induction or is there an easier way to get this?

Comment: I edited your question in [$\LaTeX$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Please check if I changed the meaning of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On seeing the question you can infer that n should  be of the form $a^{k}$ where a and k are integers.

As a starting point let us take $a=p$, $p$ is prime. Now $\tau(p^{k})=k+1$. So we can assume that if $k$ is equal to $p-1$, then your condition satisfies.

As primes are infinite, the number of solutions for your problem are infinite.

I really doubt if there exists some similar result for composite numbers.

Answer (score 1):

For any prime $p$, let $n=p^{p-1}$. Then $\tau(n)=p$ and hence $n=\tau(n)^{\tau(n)-1}$.